# VS Code settings to enable editor code folding for C# anonymous objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In the editor of VS Code I am given the option to `fold` code lines for new typed object instantiations. However, this does not work when I create an anonymous object. Is there an option in VS code to enable this? I know this is only of cosmetic nature.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing its just an incomplete feature. I doubt there's an explicit option for that.

Comment: Incidentally this also does not work in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I realised this by chance, but VS Code now seems to support it. I can collapse anonymous object instantiations. I am not sure when this was enabled. Also, I cannot check if this is also true in VS.